# Looping do...while uncertainty

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while, inputmismatchexception

In the catch block, I'm trying to correct for user bad-input issues. When testing it, if I use the "break" keyword, it doesn't jump to the initial question. If I use "continue", it loops infinitely. "Sc.next();" doesn't seem to resolve it either.

Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
public class ComputerAge {
    private static int age;
    private static int year;
    private static int month;
    private static int date;
    private static Calendar birthdate;

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the numeral representing your birth month: ");
        do {
            try {
                month = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime){
                System.out.println("Your respone must be a whole number");
                break;
            }
        } while (!sc.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: `break` breaks out of the loop, and continues executing instructions coming *after* the loop. Why do you use an exception, and not the result of `hasNextInt()`, to check whether the user entered an int?

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the "break" keyword. I thought it would simply jump back into the next outer shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fix the problem, we should identify what we want to accomplish at the end.
We want the month to be a numeral month, that is number > 0.

**Thus:**

- If a user fill a correct number `month` will be filled.
- Otherwise, Exception will be thrown and `month` will stay as '0'.

**Conclusion:** We want our program will keep running when month is equals 0.

The solution is pretty simple:

While condition should be:

```
while (month == 0);
```

And you should change `break` to `sc.next()`.

Comment: Thank you, so very much, Orel! When I'm finished with this I'm going to keep practicing these  loops until I get it!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that when you call `sc.nextInt()` and it throws an exception, `Scanner` does *not* advance its reading position. You need to advance the reading pointer by calling `sc.next()` inside the `catch` block instead of the `break`:

```
do {
    try {
        month = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime){
        System.out.println("Your respone must be a whole number");
        sc.next(); // This will advance the reading position
    }
} while (!sc.hasNextInt());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use an infinite loop, and when the input is correct (no exception thrown), use `break` to finish the loop:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter the numeral representing your birth month: ");
    do {
        try {
            int month = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Your respone must be a whole number");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Also, you will have to use `sc.nextLine()` in the `catch` block because when you enter some input and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a new-line character is added, and `nextInt()` doesn't read it. You have to use `nextLine()` to consume that character. For further information about this issue [you could read this](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about "sc.nextLine()." Now I understand why it would simply stop.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to avoid use try/catch in iteratives sentences in order to improve perfomance.

You can recode for the break to work in this way (keep in mind that de do-while will execute at least one time, so if your scanner retrieve null value, you will have nullPointer)

```
    try {
       while (sc != null && !sc.hasNextInt()) {
            month = sc.nextInt();
        } 
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("Your respone must be a whole number");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can get the integer first, and use regular expressions. Don't use exceptions if possible to enforce code logic.

```
int month;
boolean correct = false;
while (!correct && sc.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (!line.matches("^[0-9]+$"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your response must be a whole number");
        correct = false;
    }
    else
    {
        month = Integer.parseInt(line);
        correct = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a regexp when scanner.hasNextInt() does that for you?

Comment: I'll try to avoid it. I had the impression that this was what the professor wanted since catching errors was the subject of his lecture but if it's bad coding, I'll avoid it if I can.